# John is my brother. or My brother is john

Tags: possessives

Which is more frequent or correct?

1.John is my brother. or My brother is john.

2.John is the doctor. or The doctor is John.

Comment: They are both common and correct. But context and what you want to stress are important factors. For instance, who you are talking to and for what reason/purpose can quickly call for a different word order. But for simplicity, I'll stick with my first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CarSmack says, both are idiomatic and either may be used. What determines *which* you use is the **context**.

In sentences like this one of the terms joined by *BE*, *John* or *my brother* will (ordinarily) have been introduced into the discourse already; for instance, someone may have asked you:

> Who is your brother?  *OR*
>   Who is John?

When you answer this question, that piece will now be 'old information'; the other term will be 'new information'; and the characteristic position for the 'new information' in the sentence is after the verb *BE*.

> Who is your brother?  —My brother is **John**.
>   Who is John? —John is **my brother**.

Comment: I have another question.1.John is a doctor and David was John's brother. 2. John is a doctor and His(John's) brother was David. my question is, according to above two sentences which is the correct noun clause? 1.John, whose brother **David** **was**,(is a doctor.) or 2.John,whose brother **was** **David**,(is a doctor.)

Comment: @Dinusha Again, has David been introduced yet? (The tenses are odd, so I'm changing them.) If he has, then *whose  *whose brother David is*--but we would be more likely to say *who is David's brother*. If he has not been introduced, then *whose brother is David*. If so, then - but we would be more likely to say *John is a doctor, and his brother is David.*